# Unset session in PHP and submit form using onClick with only 1 button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, session

I need to submit a form and unset the session on submit at the same time on click.

This is currently my form and button :

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formID">
    //content here
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_req" value="submit_req" 
        onclick="submitForm('insert_man_order.php')">Submit Request</button>
</form>
```

This is my PHP for unsetting the session and resetting the value of my variable :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_req'])){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val){
            $val == 0;
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

**JS :**

```
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('formID').action = action;
    document.getElementById('formID').submit();
}
```

The form submission is working but the session and `$val` are not unsetting/resetting. Any help will be appreaciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you put session_start() on top of that php page?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek yes I did

Comment: Where are you setting empty($_SESSION['cart']) before you unset it..?done

Comment: try it in form submit instead of button <form onsubmit=submitForm('insert_man_order.php')">

Comment: and remove function submitForm(action)'s second line

Comment: @MohammedShafeek I used an onClick because I am also using the form to update the table. So there's an Update and Submit. That's why I am asking if there's another way that I can execute the PHP and javascript at the same time onClick of the Submit button.

Comment: ya..you can decide the form action page dynamically using javascript like you did..and if any validations there in javascript you can use onsubmit= return submitForm('insert_man_order.php')" in form submit,and if validation fails you just return false..then the form won't submit..

Answer (score 1):

Use [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) to destory all session variables. **If** it doesn't work you can try below snippet to totally delete everything and start new.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: That make no sense if he want to remove just `cart` session and not all sessions and why you think `unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);` will not do the work?

Answer (score -1):

change `$val==0 to $val=0`
it will help you.
thanks